# Using Socket or Http Request passing data different node.js servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, devops

Everyone that's a bit of a strange question.

I have a product(a Node.js Backend) that's I sell and people deploy it by themselves.

And my goal now is to make them sending data to each other if they want.

they are deployed on private servers.

The data is simple text(writing some text send it to other servers).

it needs to be end-to-end encrypted.

It's not a flow of data in continue(chat Room).

they should have the possibility to send to multiple different servers.

I don't want to use a third-party server to host everything and save the data(they have their own MongoDB Local).

And I don't really know where to start and what to use.

My first problem is do I use regular HTTP requests or WebSocket or any other technology?

Comment: The description is a little vague. What kind of data will they be sharing? What exactly will that look like (is it like a form or like a zip file or what)? If it doesn't need to be real time or super fast I think a websocket might be overkill and you might be better off just persisting it in a database of some sort. Does your app already have a database you're using? If so I'd create a new table in there for this.

Comment: Additional question: are all instances deployed publicly and can connect to each other? Or are they in private networks or access is restricted by a firewall or similar.

Comment: Question Edited.